# Custom checkbox show or hide custom notice in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Im new in this coding stuff, I researched many sites now and try to build my own checkout field in Woocommerce. It should be a checkout field, when it is checked, some information or warning should plop up, it worked with showing on checkout page normal, but my script doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_checkout_fields' );
function add_custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['checkbox_trigger'] = array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'label'     => __('You dont live in Germany?', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );
    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'echo_notice_billing' );
function echo_notice_billing() {
    echo '<div class="billing-notice woocommerce-info" style="display:none">It may take forever</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'show_notice_billing' );
function show_notice_billing(){ 
    ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('checkbox_trigger').change(function(){
                if(this.checked){
                    $('billing-notice').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('billing-notice').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your jQuery script… Try to replace your related function by this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'show_notice_billing' );
function show_notice_billing(){
    ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('#checkbox_trigger').click(function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked') ){
                    $('.billing-notice').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('.billing-notice').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Tested and works.